# Images not exporting to Jar file

Tags: java, image, jar, export

I'm trying to export a Java project to a Jar file but the images are not exporting with it.

This is the code to the image im using

```
static Icon logo = new ImageIcon("src/images/logo.png");

 // LOGO
    JLabel imageLogo = new JLabel(logoOne); 
    imageLogo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
```

Ive read you need to factor it into the build path but even after i do that it still doesn't export. Do i need to change my code as well? Or am i factoring it into build path wrong?

Comment: If you're using eclipse, then in the build path of the project, there is a tab called order and export. Check the package you would like to be exported to the `jar` file in that tab and then build the jar.

Comment: Every box is ticked in there and i still cant see the logo after export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to change my code as well?

Yep.  That code is presuming the `String` to represent a path to a `File`.

By the time of deployment, it will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).

That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

> Images not exporting to Jar file..

To check for sure, do something like:

```
jar -tvf the.jar
```